# Assigning NSInteger property in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite I want to insert data in that table. The table has responses_id,  participant_id, answer_text, answer_option_update_date_time. responses_id and participant_id are integers. When I am assigning any thing to participant_id it gives an error, object can not set to property.

```
@interface Coffee : NSObject {

NSInteger coffeeID;
NSInteger participant_Id;

NSString*question_Id;
NSString*answer_option;
NSString*answer_text;
NSString*update_date_time;




//Intrnal variables to keep track of the state of the object.
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger coffeeID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger participant_Id;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *question_Id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *answer_option;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *answer_text;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *update_date_time;


- (void)save_Local {
    CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];

    coffeeObj.participant_Id=mynumber;

    NSString*question="1";
    coffeeObj.question_Id=question;
    coffeeObj.answer_option=selectionAnswerOption;
    coffeeObj.answer_text=professionTextField.text;




    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    UPDATE_DATE_TIME=str;


    coffeeObj.update_date_time=UPDATE_DATE_TIME;

    //Add the object
    [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];  
}
```

When I am assigning a value to participant_id it gives an error.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`NSInteger` is not a class, it is a basic type like an `int` or `long`. On iOS `NSInteger` is `typedef`ed to an `int`, on OS X it is `typedef`ed to a `long`.  Therefore, you shouldn't try to `retain` an `NSInteger`.  You should change your property declaration to:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger participant_Id;
```

The same goes for your `coffeeID` property.

Comment: If you do want it to be an object, you can wrap it in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: No problem. It is a common confusion for people to think `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are classes.

Comment: and how to pass value to class?